# Devise not recognizing TravisCI ENV variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, travis-ci

I maintain an opensource Ruby on Rails app that uses Travis for continuous integration.

I am having issues getting the build to pass when I attempt to configure Devise / Rails like this:

In devise.rb:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.secret_key = ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE']
# . . .
end
```

In secret_token.rb:

```
OpenFarm::Application.config.secret_key_base = ENV['SECRET_KEY']
```

In my travisCI settings, I have set SECRET_KEY to a value obtained from running `rake secret`.

I get the classic devise no secret key error when building:

`raise_no_secret_key': Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer: (RuntimeError)`

Why is Rails unable to see the ENV vars that I set from the TravisCI web settings panel?

I noticed that if I allow certain variables to be set as not secret, they will be exposed to the application. This is not practical for all of my ENV vars, especially given that this is an open source project.

**UPDATE:** After some reading, it turns out that Travis does not expose secure ENV vars to untrusted builds, such as pull requests. This is due to the fact that a malicious user could trigger a build that would expose the ENV vars (eg, submit a pull request that uploads ENV vars to a remote server). After some thought, it is obvious I will need to find a different approach to what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to access SECRET_KEY_BASE directly from ENV, but you are setting it  with OpenFarm::Application.config.secret_key_base

So it should be something like this:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.secret_key = Application.config.secret_key_base
# . . .
end
```

OR:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.secret_key = ENV['SECRET_KEY']
# . . .
end
```

Comment: Why would that matter if they are both the same value?

Comment: Why would what matter?  If you are going to set SECRET_KEY_BASE to SECRET_KEY, why not use SECRET_KEY directly?

Comment: How does that solve any problem though? They are effectively the same thing since they return the same value. It does not solve the issue.

Comment: Based on your original post, it seemed like your problem of "Devise.secret_key was not set" was due to you setting Application.config.secret_key_base, but trying to access it through ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE']. Was I misinterpreting the problem?